# completely remove flash game that embed in web page also remove from memory

Tags: actionscript-3, swfobject

I made a flash game that embed in web page, and the game normally increasing memory when playing it. that's no problem.

now I need to remove this game from web page, by now I just know remove the html node that contain swf :

```
$("flash_container").html("");
```

or

```
swfobject.removeSWF("flash_game_Id");
```

yes, after above operation, the flash game disappeared. But the big problem is that the memory that flash game used still there. Why it would not decrease.

actually, I would embed more swf in the web page, and that would eat up large memory even I remove swf frome the web page.

does anybody know how to decreas memory when remove swf frome web page?

Comment: The browser should handle it's memory for you, you don't have any way to de-allocate memory from it. I would check that your swf cleans up its memory correctly just encase there is a leak but there is nothing in the browser that you can do.

Comment: thank you for answer~! I had found a solution. that is create a swf that only do load the main swf and unload main swf. It works.

Answer (score 0):

now I created a loader.swf special for loading main game swf, and embed to html. when need to remove the game from html, first of all, telling main game swf do clean work, then let loader.swf to unload the main game swf, finally, remove the swf container div from html. it works fine.